# Find nearest neighbors

Tags: python, pandas, nearest-neighbor

I have a large dataframe of the form:

```
    user_id  time_interval  A      B       C       D       E       F       G       H    ... Z
0   12166    2.0            3.0    1.0     1.0     1.0     3.0     1.0     1.0     1.0  ... 0.0
1   12167    0.0            0.0    1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  ... 0.0
2   12168    0.0            0.0    1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  ... 0.0
3   12169    0.0            0.0    1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  ... 0.0
4   12170    0.0            0.0    1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  ... 0.0
... ...      ...            ...    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  ... ...
```

I would like to find, for each user_id, based on the columns A-Z as coordinates,the closest neighbors within a 'radius' distance r. The output should look like, for example, for r=0.1:

```
user_id    neighbors
12166      [12251,12345, ...]
12167      [12168, 12169,12170, ...]
...        ...
```

I tried for-looping throughout the user_id list but it takes ages.
I did something like this:

```
import scipy
neighbors = []
for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    user_neighbors = [dataframe["user_id"][j] for j in range(i+1,len(dataframe)) if scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(dataframe.values[i][2:],dataframe.values[j][2:])<0.1]
    neighbors.append([dataframe["user_id"][i],user_neighbors])
```

and I have been waiting for hours.
Is there a pythonic way to improve this?

Comment: Please also share with us what you have already tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited. I I tried for-looping throughout the user_id list but it takes ages

Comment: @stellasia I don't know why the try I did, didn't appear in the first edition. I just re-edited again the question and now it is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've done it using `apply` method.
The dummy data consisting of columns A-D with an added column for neighbors:

```
print(df)
user_id  time_interval  A  B  C  D  neighbors
0    12166              2  3  2  2  3        NaN
1    12167              0  1  4  3  3        NaN
2    12168              0  4  3  3  1        NaN
3    12169              0  2  2  3  2        NaN
4    12170              0  3  3  1  1        NaN
```

the custom function:

```
def func(row):
    r = 2.5 # the threshold
    out = df[(((df.iloc[:, 2:-1] - row[2:-1])**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5).le(r)]['user_id'].to_list()
    out.remove(row['user_id'])
    df.loc[row.name, ['neighbors']] = str(out)
df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

the output:

```
   print(df):
   user_id  time_interval  A  B  C  D              neighbors
   0    12166              2  3  2  2  3         [12169, 12170]
   1    12167              0  1  4  3  3                [12169]
   2    12168              0  4  3  3  1         [12169, 12170]
   3    12169              0  2  2  3  2  [12166, 12167, 12168]
   4    12170              0  3  3  1  1         [12166, 12168]
```

Let me know if it outperforms the for-loop approach.

Comment: With the first anwer I get `IndexingError: Too many indexers`
With the recent editor there is a problem since df is not defined as an argument now, so it doesn't work either

Comment: First if gives df is not defined, because it is not defined within the function.
So, I changed everything to df, I mean, row=df, then it says `Too many indexers` which is in the line of the .iloc

Comment: df should be the same name as the name of your dataframe and it doesn't need to be defined in your function. Let row be as it was, it contains the row which apply is currently handling.